Error: Cannot find module 'C:\vite\bin\vite.js'
'React' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\vite\bin\vite.js'

Node.js v18.4.0
I realised that this issue can be fixed, by avoiding using special characters such as & in the folder names. Once this was corrected, npm run dev worked as expected.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
